# Preferred method of updating and setting SQL

Tags: sql, sql-update, set, correctness

I'm learning SQL at the moment, and have found some different methods of updating and setting a table.

For this example, I am wondering what is the "most correct way" of doing this?

```
    UPDATE student
    SET test1 = 7, test2 = 9
    where stuid = 999
```

or

```
    UPDATE student
    SET test1 = 7
    where stuid = 999
    UPDATE student
    SET test2 = 9
    where stuid = 999
```

Thanks.

Comment: Number 1....................

Comment: I would say method1 without any doubt ... why to use two queries if we can use 1...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly always Google yourself before posting any Questions.

The answer (as said by others) is off-course the **Method 1**.
As it will not reload the database **Twice.**

Also if you are Beginner try to go learn from **[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/)**

Comment: i actually did google and that's what prompted me to ask the question :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446250/sql-statement-with-multiple-sets-and-wheres

Here, i can see that almost every single answer states to use MULTIPLE statements, where only one answer uses 'method 1' in my OP, which everyone here is stating is correct.

Comment: It that Particular **Question**, as the heading Suggests the **OP** wants to update multiple column with **multiple Where condition**. But in your case you are updating on same **where Condition**.

Comment: Ah! I overlooked that part! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Running one update statement is always better than two. **I choose the first one**. It will only run on the database once and updates two columns.

Answer (score 1):

I will go with first statement because its just 1 call to database server.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the first, don't repeat yourself, and always write neat codes.

Answer (score 1):

Statement 1 is without any doubt better than statement 2 ...
Why to load the db server twice than required ...