# PHP update multiple rows with multiple WHERES doenst work

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mysqli, sql-update

I want to update multiple rows with multiple wheres.
When i update only 1 input field it works perfecly, but when i update diffrent weeks and field the query fails. I dont know how to put this code togetter. I already search on google and stackoverflow but could not find something that fits my question.

here is my code

```
if(isset($_POST["opslaan"]))
        {
            unset($_POST["opslaan"]);

            foreach($_POST as $input => $inner_arr)
            {
                foreach($inner_arr as $week => $value)
                {
                    $update_query[] = $input." = '".$value."' WHERE week = ".$week;
                }
            }

            $test   = implode(", ", $update_query);

            echo $test;

            if(mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE buitenklimaat SET ".$test))
            {
                header("location: dashboard.php?user=1&page=gewasregistratie");
                echo "done";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Failed !";
            }
        }
```

echo output:

```
gem_buitentemperatuur_etmaal = '1' WHERE week = 1, 
gem_buitentemperatuur_etmaal = '2' WHERE week = 2, 
gem_buitentemperatuur_etmaal = '3' WHERE week = 3
```

Comment: You do realize that `WHERE week = ".$week` is being added multiple times, right? Can you paste what `$test` returns?

Comment: There should be only a single [`WHERE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Comment: what is the output of echo $test; and check the final query output using  `echo "UPDATE buitenklimaat SET ".$test`

Comment: DUmp your final sql statement and execute it in an interactive sql client. That is the easiest way to understand why your sql query is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "UPDATE buitenklimaat SET ";

foreach($_POST as $input => $inner_arr)
{
    $query .= $input.' = CASE ';

    foreach($inner_arr as $week => $value)
    {
        $query .= ' WHEN week = '.$week. ' THEN '.$value;
    }

    $query .= ' ELSE '.$input.' END , ';
}

$query = rtrim($query, ', ');
```

Not tested, can you see what $query outputs?

Update: Added $input_array
Update 2: Trimming the last comma
Update 3: Restructured loop

Comment: **+1** for the `CASE` Illustration.

Comment: Nice example indeed and it works, There is only 1 but... gem_buitentemperatuur_etmaal is not the only field i need to update, i have 45+ field with diffrent weeks to update IF the user wants to.

Comment: Gonna try this give me 15 min

Comment: Query doesnt fail, but only updates the last week.
UPDATE buitenklimaat SET gem_buitentemperatuur_etmaal = CASE WHEN week = 1 THEN 12 END, gem_buitentemperatuur_etmaal = CASE WHEN week = 2 THEN 4 END, gem_buitentemperatuur_etmaal = CASE WHEN week = 3 THEN 67 END, gem_buitentemperatuur_etmaal = CASE WHEN week = 4 THEN 23 END

Comment: I think I get now what you mean, please check again.

Comment: Hi, i almost works like it should, When i update 10 weeks for example it works perfecly. But when i update week 1 and 2 the other 8 weeks become empty somehow...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45637/discussion-between-user007-and-julez)

Comment: After the discussion works like a charm !! Thank you mate for youre time

Comment: ya this approach is definately better than mine +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not update multiple fields like that.

Look at answers in this question [SQL Statement with multiple SET's and WHERE's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446250/sql-statement-with-multiple-sets-and-wheres)

Also do not forget to sanitize your input, taking values directly from $_POST and putting them into a query is asking for a [SQL Injection](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jKylhJtPmI).

Comment: Yes i know, thanks for that. I wanted first to get the code works then adding security.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to do

```
update
set 
where
where
where
```

**which is wrong**.

An update query can have only one `where` clause.

```
Update
set //can have multiple set clause
where//only one where clause
```

**now what you can do is:**

```
foreach($_POST as $input => $inner_arr)
            {
                foreach($inner_arr as $week => $value)
                {
                  $update_query[] = $input." = '".$value."' WHERE week = ".$week;
                  $test   = implode(", ", $update_query);
                   if(mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE buitenklimaat SET ".$test))
                    {
                    header("location: dashboard.php?user=1&page=gewasregistratie");
                    echo "done";
                     }
                    else
                     {
                     echo "Failed !";
                     }
                }
            }
```

Comment: But what i need to do when i got diffrent weeks to update ? for example WHERE week = 1, WHERE week = 2, WHERE week = 4

Comment: Okey, this works and i understand whats happening. But is this slow when u update 120 querys ? or more.

Comment: @Julez if this approach slows your query then you should use CASE.

Comment: Yes i was planning to, but i could not do it yet

Answer (score 1):

You are creating query wrong. Traditional way to perform multiple updates is to create multiple update query in a single string and execute them in one go like as follow

```
UPDATE buitenklimaat  SET Category_ID = 10 WHERE week  = 2;
UPDATE buitenklimaat  SET Category_ID = 9  WHERE week  = 3;
UPDATE buitenklimaat  SET Category_ID = 12 WHERE week  = 4;
UPDATE buitenklimaat  SET Category_ID = 11 WHERE week  = 5;
```

Or there is another way describe by Karl Rixon

```
UPDATE buitenklimaat  
    SET Category_ID = CASE week 
        WHEN 2 THEN 10 
        WHEN 3 THEN 9
        WHEN 4 THEN 12
        WHEN 5 THEN 11
        ELSE Category_ID
    END
```

You can read further about it through following link

Source: http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/

Comment: Thanks i wil read the article, its kinda hard to read the CASE. But i will take a good look at it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `WHERE`, you could write `AND` and put the `WHERE` in the `UPDATE` string before the test variable, where you'll have all the requisites