# SQL multi SET with one WHERE

Tags: sql, database, set, where-clause

Similar to this question : [SQL Statement with multiple SETs and WHEREs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446250/sql-statement-with-multiple-sets-and-wheres)

Is there a way to perform multiple sets, as shown below.

```
UPDATE  table
SET ID = 111111259
SET Name = "Bob"
SET Phone = 1111111261
WHERE ID = 2555
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I was figuring it out.. slowly :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is possible,

```
UPDATE table SET Name = 'aaa', Col2 = 'bbb' WHERE ID IN (2555, 2666)
```

What you are asking for is setting multiple values to same column and same row.

Comment: Sorry, i can see how my example is very unclear. I want to set multiple fields in one row. - i updated the question

Answer (score 3):

No need of `SET` for each column. do it like

```
UPDATE  table
SET ID = 111111259,
Name = 'Bob',
Phone = 1111111261
WHERE ID = 2555
```

Answer (score 1):

No.  There is no way to do what your query suggests.  You are trying to set the same column, ID, to three different values.  What is sql supposed to do in this case?  You can set multiple columns in the same update statement, but you can't set the same column to three different values.

To update multiple columns, use a comma.

```
UPDATE  table
SET ID = 111111259,
Name = 'Bob',
Phone = 1111111261
WHERE ID = 2555
```

Comment: @user3845646 Edited anser.