# SQL query for update a table with different values in the same column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have these tables:

**tblPart**

```
ID, field1, field2, ecc
```

**tblUserFreeProperty**

```
ID_tblPart, ID, identname, val
```

I need to write a query to update `tblUserFreeProperty`, but only the val filed when `tblPart.ID = tblUserFreeProperty.ID` and `identname` has a specific value.

In the database, `identname` has one of 8 possible values, and I need to update all of them.

I have wrote a query for only one value at time:

```
UPDATE tblUserFreeProperty
SET val = N'??_??@True;'
FROM tblUserFreeProperty 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPart ON tblUserFreeProperty.id = tblPart.id
WHERE tblUserFreeProperty.id  = N'3' 
  AND (tblUserFreeProperty.identname = N'DSR_Mag.Gestito')
```

Is there a way to write the update query for all 8 different values at the same time?

Added explanation: I need a query like this:

```
UPDATE tblUserFreeProperty
SET val1 = N'??_??@True;, val2 = N'??_??@False;', val3 = N'5', val4 = N'BK',...val8
FROM tblUserFreeProperty 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPart ON tblUserFreeProperty.id = tblPart.id
WHERE (tblUserFreeProperty.id = N'3' AND (tblUserFreeProperty.identname = N'DSR_Mag.Gestito'))->SET Val1
   OR (tblUserFreeProperty.id = N'3' AND (tblUserFreeProperty.identname = N'DSR_Mag.Done'))->SET Val2
  OR (tblUserFreeProperty.id = N'3' AND (tblUserFreeProperty.identname = N'Something Else'))->SET val3
```

I hope it is more clear

Comment: What do you mean by you need to "upgrade" the value?

Comment: If you want to use multiple different values for `identname`, why not use an `IN` clause?

Comment: I think what you are after is a CASE WHEN ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE .... END statement
See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766102/i-want-to-use-case-statement-to-update-some-records-in-sql-server-2005

Comment: In the tblUserFreeProperty I have 8 different values. I need to upgrade all of them. In this moment with the SET I'm ok with one, but If I need to change this "tblUserFreeProperty.identname = N'DSR_Mag.Gestito'" I have to rewrite the query.

Comment: *"I need to upgrade all of them."* What does "upgrading" them mean? You haven't clarified this.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained your problem very well but hopefully this helps

```
UPDATE tblUserFreeProperty
SET    val = N'??_??@True;', anotherColumn = 5, anotherOne = 'Something'
FROM   tblUserFreeProperty LEFT OUTER JOIN
              tblPart ON tblUserFreeProperty.id = tblPart.id
WHERE         tblUserFreeProperty.id  = N'3' 
and (tblUserFreeProperty.identname = N'DSR_Mag.Gestito')
```

EDIT: Adding the explanation and code below with another solution to the question which might be better suited, even though I still don't truly understand the question.

Here's how it'd look with more than one condition which you can add with OR

```
UPDATE tblUserFreeProperty
SET    val = N'??_??@True;'
FROM   tblUserFreeProperty LEFT OUTER JOIN
              tblPart ON tblUserFreeProperty.id = tblPart.id
WHERE         (tblUserFreeProperty.id  = N'3' 
and (tblUserFreeProperty.identname = N'DSR_Mag.Gestito')) OR (tblUserFreeProperty.id  = N'45435' 
and (tblUserFreeProperty.identname = N'Something')) OR (tblUserFreeProperty.id  = N'394290' 
and (tblUserFreeProperty.identname = N'Something Else'))
```

The way **OR** works is very simple. It checks if the first brackets are **TRUE**, if not then the second, if not the third. If **ANY** are **TRUE** then it does the **UPDATE**, if not then obviously it doesn't.

Comment: I'm sorry for my explanation. Your replay solve just a case. I know I can set more then one value, but the problem is the Where statement. If tblUserFreeProperty.identname = Val1 this works. But I have 8 different Where. The colums in the tblUserFreeProperty are only two with the values i need to change.

Comment: If you need it to happen for different conditions then just add some with OR. Look at the change I'm gonna make to my answer

Comment: The Where condition with the or it's ok, but the problem is also to set a different value in the right condition.

Comment: So you want to set 8 different values on 8 different conditions? For example if someone is 8 years old you want to change their age to 'Eight' if they are 9 years old you want to change it to 'nine' if 10 to 'ten' and so on? Or am I not understanding?

Comment: I have make a modification in my original question for better explain the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Though I could not get exactly what is required from your question. Please check if the below could serve the purpose of replacing the eight-string with the required values.

```
UPDATE       tblUserFreeProperty
SET           val =  '??_??@True;'
where  id IN (SELECT tblPart.id FROM tblPart) 
and  identname IN ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't set differtent values of one column in the same time...
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784653/sql-multi-set-with-one-where[enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24784653/sql-multi-set-with-one-where%5Benter)

I findout the answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).